# Convert Optional<Double> to String

Tags: swift, integer, double

This is the code I'm using so far to get the location (in this case latitude) of a calendar event.

```
let latitude = event.structuredLocation?.geoLocation?.coordinate.latitude
print(latitude) // Optional<Double>

print("\(String(describing: latitude))") // not working
```

Because the type of latitude is `Optional<Double>` I'd like to just get back a String with the value *(like "49,9202221")*.

EDIT:

```
if let latitude = event.structuredLocation?.geoLocation?.coordinate.latitude {
     print(latitude) // gets rounded - How to avoid this?
}
```

> How to convert this value to a string **without displaying** `"Optional(...)"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unwrap latitude as following:

```
if let latitude = event.structuredLocation?.geoLocation?.coordinate.latitude {
     print(String(format: "%.16f", latitude)) // change 16 to the number of digits that you want after comma
} else {
     print("latitude is nil")
}
```

Comment: But not with `geoLocation`. The latitude value gets rounded. Can I avoid this? @Anton Kondrashov

Comment: Can you show the output? I don't understand how much rounded.

Comment: `Optional(23.829600769999997)` -->
`23.82960077`